# CSS Layout and border issue

Tags: css, html, layout

I am facing some weird layout/positioning issues in my webpage. It has mostly to do with floated items and container borders that don't flow right. I have tried clearing and overflow: auto, hidden but it still does not work.

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: What is your problem in this??

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: auto;` to `.explore-inner`

```
.explore-inner {
border: 1px solid #EBEBEA;
background: url(../images/inner-bg.png) repeat-x;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the suggestions. I closely followed all of the tips and used overflow and clearing and the layout looks much better. 

But there is still a background image issue (the bg is cut short and there is white space)at the bottom of http://domainandseo.com/porfolio/villa/index.html

Similar background issue at
http://domainandseo.com/porfolio/villa/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `<ul>` items have a float, this is not cleared correctly. Right after the `<ul>` items in `.explore-inner` you have have a `clear: both;`

Answer (score 0):

Add this following css

```
.explore-inner:after{
    content: '.';
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
visibility: hidden;
font-size: 0;
line-height: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
clear:both;
```

}

because "ul" has floating it needs to be cleared after the "explore-inner" class

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have used `floating` in your `child div's` not `cleared` your `parent div's` so i have given the `overflow:hidden` to your parent `div` so its working fine now....

So you can update your `css` with mine one i hope this will work for you :-

**CSS**

```
.explore-inner {
    background: url("../images/inner-bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid #EBEBEA;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#team-message {
    background: url("../images/outer-bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 940px;
}
```